# How to replace all elements in list 1 with all elements from list 2 in defined function Python3

Tags: python, list, function, replace, python-3.6

I have 2 lists and ready built pass and print of a function. I can replace each element of 1st list with each element of 2nd list separately but I am not sure how to do it all together in a function. I have searched for answers here on stackoverflow for hours now, but all the python stuff here on this subject is so old and not compatible with python 3.6. I hope you can give me a hint what to use without the use of any imported methods (e.g. if/elif or something else). Here is what I have so far:

```
    def goodbadString(string):
    for (a,b) in zip(strings, expectedResults):
        string = string.replace(strings[0],expectedResults[0])
    return string

strings = ['It has been a good and bad day', 'bad company',
           'good is as good does!', 'Clovis is a big city.']
expectedResults = ['I am confused', 'goodbye', 'hello',
                   'hello and goodbye']
for string, expectedResult in zip(strings, expectedResults):
    print('Sample string = ', string)
    print('Expected result =', expectedResult)
    print('Actual result =', goodbadString(string))
    print()
```

**This is expected result (*not the whole result though*)**

[image]

you can see that my function did show the right result for a first "Sample string" but now I should continue for the rest of the elements (actual result for a second sample "goodbye" and so on).

Comment: It doesn't work because you only refer to the first element explicitly - `string.replace(strings[0],expectedResults[0])`, so no matter how many data you have, you always work with first element in each list. I'd suggest you to stop searching for answer on Internet and instead think through your code or run it with debugger, go step by step and see what's happening.

Comment: @BorisSerebrov yes, it works explicitly for the 1st element because I didn't finish for the rest. I tried to and it would give me either one of the elements but not all.  I am not sure how to continue my function correcting (syntax) that it will include all 3 elements.

Comment: @BorisSerebrov I in particular like your last suggestion.

Comment: I did try matching words and replacing them, but it will print the rest of the sentence of the element which I don't need. I also tried indexing- same things with replacing elements of lists - only works for either one but not for all...

Comment: What is `goodbadString()` supposed to do? Could you, please, re-formulate your problem more clearly?

Comment: @Rish is this a learning exercise? I am just not sure if giving a direct answer here will help you actually learn something. Maybe try using `a` and `b` in your `goodbadString` function. Also you can try doing it without a `for` loop (you can use list.index() method for that)

Comment: @BorisSerebrov I am learning things. Indexing that is suggested by AGN Gazer is brilliant and very simple, but I didn't study it just yet. I was thinking actually  getting it all in for loop with if-elif-else statement. I believe I am doing something wrong, because my result returns "none" I usually use pythontutor.com to track my steps to understand where I should make corrections. So far, I hit the wall :))))

Comment: @Rish OK, so your for loop works too with `string = string.replace(a, b)`, but `strings.index` is clearer and probably faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what do you want `goodbadString()` exactly to do. Here is an attempt:

```
def goodbadString(string):
    idx = strings.index(string)
    return string.replace(strings[idx],expectedResults[idx])

Sample string =  It has been a good and bad day
Expected result = I am confused
Actual result = I am confused

Sample string =  bad company
Expected result = goodbye
Actual result = goodbye

Sample string =  good is as good does!
Expected result = hello
Actual result = hello

Sample string =  Clovis is a big city.
Expected result = hello and goodbye
Actual result = hello and goodbye
```

This is actually stupid... Simply return expected string without bothering to replace anything:

```
def goodbadString(string):
    return expectedResults[strings.index(string)]
```

Comment: that is exactly what I needed. Too bad we didn't study "idx" yet. I assumed there would be a longer code. Maybe there is a good book I can get to learn more complex exercises? I would appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: wow, that last part you added is so simple and does it all! I am very new to coding as you can see...

Comment: Personally, I am kind of against books, especially on Python (as opposite, e.g., of books on algorithms) - Python is well documented and there are plenty of examples online. I think the best approach is to try to make up yourself some (however silly/stupid) problems and try to solve them AND improve them. Especially, try to follow @BorisSerebrov suggestion _"... think through your code or run it with debugger, go step by step and see what's happening."_ You can replace debugger with a simple `print` statement for now. Just do not give up too soon and persevere.

Comment: @Rish To add to my previous comment... Thinking through your code, in my opinion, is the most important thing. Effectively you become your own compiler/interpreter.

Comment: oh I am very stubborn, usually I figure things out :)